# How to conceal multiple characters without making text dance upon hovering?

Tags: conceal

Say that I have pattern `aaaaapple` in my text file, and say that I configured vim so that it conceals `a\+`.

What will happen is that, if `conceallevel=1`, then `aaaaapple` will become `_pple`. Note that `aaaaa` is replaced by a single space `_` (I'm writing spaces as `_` due to technical difficulties).  This causes the line to jiggle/dance every time I hover on the concealed word, due to the single space `_` expanding into 5 characters `aaaaa`.

What I want is to conceal `aaaaapple` such that it becomes `_____pple` instead of `_pple`.  This way, when I move to the line where this conceal happened, the text won't jiggle/dance by expanding/shrinking.  I.e. it looks like `_____pple` before hovering on it, and `aaaaapple` after hovering on it.  No jiggling!

Any idea how to do this conceal such that *each* concealed character is replaced by a space (and not replacing *all* concealed characters by a single space)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of matching *all* duplicate "a"s in a single match, try concealing *each* extra "a" in its own, concealed group:

```
syn match HideAa "a\zea" conceal
```

Because this conceals only a single "a" with its own syntax group conceal, it will effectively apply a concealing space to each "a".

Comment: Thanks.  It works!  An extra variation: is it possible to make this conceal apply only when `aaaaapple` is prefixed by, say, `xx?  E.g. only `xxaaaaapple` becomes `_______pple`, but `aaaaapple` (without `xx`) to not become `_____pple`?

Comment: You can do it with 2 commands together: `syn match HideAa "a\zea" conceal contained` and `syn match HideXxAa "xxa\+" contains=HideAa`

Comment: Something to note: this will "consume" the first `a`, so that no other match can overlap with it

Answer (score 1):

See `:h concealcursor`. It controls which modes will be activated for conceal. In this case you want to disable it for normal mode. I recommend trying `setl concealcursor=vic`

Comment: I'm not sure the OP wants to disable conceal in normal mode—that's not my read of the question